# TFS 2010 installation: prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I've been attempting to install TFS2010 onto Windows 7 Ultimate but when I get to the Basic Configuration screen I get an the error message:

*TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.. For more information, see the configuration log.*

Previously, I had succesfully installed TFS2010 onto the same machine and had also created some projects.  However it subsequently prevented me from creating new projects (for reasons that I was not able to diagnose) and so I unstalled the app and then re-installed it hoping the error would go away.  The error I was getting before the uninstall was also contained the message "The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows"

Any ideas would be much appreciated

EXTRACT FROM ERROR LOG:

[Error  @12:07:57.652] TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.
[Info   @12:07:57.654] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnexpectedDatabaseResultException: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ResultCollection.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationCatalogService.BuildResources(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ResultCollection rc, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.CatalogTransactionContext.Save(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions, Boolean preview, List`1& deletedResources, List`1& deletedNodes)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FrameworkStepPerformer.InstallCatalogRoots(String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)
[Info   @12:07:57.654] [2011-01-05 12:07:57Z] Servicing step Install the catalog roots failed. (ServicingOperation: Install; Step group: Install.TfsFramework)
[Info   @12:07:57.686] Clearing dictionary, removing all items.
[Error  @12:07:57.688] TF255184: An error occurred during operation. Message=TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.. For more information, see the configuration log..
[Error  @12:07:57.689] 
Exception Message: Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows. (type CollectionServicingException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingContext.FinishStep(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformOperations(Boolean validateOnly, Int32 stepsToPerform)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.Execute(Int32 numberOfStepsToPerform)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationConfigurationDriver.Execute()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationDataTier.Apply(OperationContext context)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows. (type UnexpectedDatabaseResultException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ResultCollection.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationCatalogService.BuildResources(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ResultCollection rc, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.CatalogTransactionContext.Save(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions, Boolean preview, List`1& deletedResources, List`1& deletedNodes)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FrameworkStepPerformer.InstallCatalogRoots(String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)

[Error  @12:07:57.690] TF255248: The process applying the configuration must be terminated due to an error.
[Error  @12:07:57.692] TF255247: An error occurred while applying the following configuration: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigurationApplyException: TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.. For more information, see the configuration log. (Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.) ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.CollectionServicingException: Error occurred while executing servicing step Install the catalog roots for component Install.TfsFramework during Install: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnexpectedDatabaseResultException: TF14103: Internal error: The database procedure prc_SaveCatalogChanges returned the wrong number of rows.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ResultCollection.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationCatalogService.BuildResources(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, ResultCollection rc, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.CatalogTransactionContext.Save(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, CatalogQueryOptions queryOptions, Boolean preview, List`1& deletedResources, List`1& deletedNodes)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.FrameworkStepPerformer.InstallCatalogRoots(String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingContext.FinishStep(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Boolean validateOnly)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformOperations(Boolean validateOnly, Int32 stepsToPerform)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.Execute(Int32 numberOfStepsToPerform)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationConfigurationDriver.Execute()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationDataTier.Apply(OperationContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ErrorList.HandleError(IResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ErrorList.Add(IResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.OperationResult.Add(IResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationDataTier.Apply(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigurationNode.ApplyIfReady(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationTier.Install(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationTier.Apply(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigurationNode.ApplyIfReady(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.LogicalTier.Apply(OperationalMode mode).
[Info   @12:07:57.695] 
[Info   @12:07:57.695] -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Answer (score 0):

1. First install or have you tried with a couple of failures?
2. Did you make it through and then install any SP's before uninstalling?

I had a situation that I just got passed where the following happened.

1. Windows 7 Ultimate
2. TFS 2010 Basic Edition
3. TFS 2010 SP1
4. Windows 7 SP1
5. Uninstall Windows 7 SP1 (this is where all hell broke loose).
6. Slam head against desk for hours
7. Uninstall TFS 2010
8. Reapply Windows 7 SP1 (that or a rebuild.  not in the mood).
9. Install TFS 2010
10. Install TFS 2010 SP1
11. Configure TFS

Then it worked.  Tried every other combination.  SP1 causes some new problems (sleeping locks up a lot.  other random things).

Hopefully this help someone